# UITableView - How to stop touch event from getting cancelled when drag starts?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I’ve implemented touches touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded and touchesCancelled in a UITableView that has dragInteractionEnabled = true. On touching the tableView the touchesBegan is called but after sometime the drag starts and the touchesCancelled is invoked automatically. Is there a way to maintain touches until the user lifts the finger off the tableView?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesBegan")
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesEnded")
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesMoved")
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesCancelled")
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I guess that the gesture used by the UITableView is handling the states, you I don't think you have something to do about it. Try to describe the use case..

Comment: I'm doing an animation on touches began and would like to do a reverse animation on touches end. Do you know of a way using which the touch doesn't get cancelled on drag start?